# regular expression to remove <b> tags for numbers

Tags: regex, notepad++, replace

I need to remove the   tags for the numbers only.. as there are some titles that are with the bold tag..  and the numbers are in the following format..

```
<br>
<b>title</b> <br>    
<br>
<b>9. </b>some text <br>
<b>10. </b>some text, <br><b>11. </b>some text. <br>
<b>12. </b>some text. <br>
<b>130. </b>some text. <br>
```

the numbers are in the format of the number then a dot then a space..

I use notepad++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find

```
<b>(\d+\. )</b>
```

replace with

```
\1
```

or whatever the syntax for "first backreference" is in notepad++